# Creating a scrollable section in a page for infinite scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want to create a section in a page and create an infinite scrolling window in it.
A friend suggested iFrame would be an option but I would like to have alternatives; either HTML or CSS. ANY IDEAS???

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is what you mean?

HTML

```
<div><!-- Content --></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g2TFU/1/

Always easier if you show a little bit of code in your question... something that you have attempted yourself.

Sam

Comment: What about the infinite part?

Comment: @misterManSam : Thank you! 
You're code was helpful!

Comment: Well if infinite scrolling is very important to you @bjb568 ...  `scroll-limit: infinite !important;` should do the trick ;)

Comment: In fact, I'm trying to create a space for an Ajax endless scroll section on a page and I didn't want to use iFrame, since it is obsolete!

Comment: Actually, iFrames aren't obsolete.

Comment: @bjb568 : elucidate please!

Comment: @Cyrus [There is no deprecated warning here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) [Nor is there here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element)